# Check if date colum is in some period which depends on another date column

Tags: mysql, sql

Well I have this part of query:

```
round(if(((t1.docType=1 and t1.installments=1) or (t1.docType=3 and t1.installend=t1.insend)), "", t1.premiaPaid),2) AS custom_field
```

The problem comes from here `t1.installend=t1.insend` where:

```
t1.installend = 2018-11-29
t1.insend = 2018-11-28
```

It returns false in this form, but I want this part of condition to returns me true, so I want to get `t1.insend` and to check i**f 2018-11-28 is in t1.installend +- 5 days**, in this example would be:

If `2018-11-28` is between `2018-11-23` and `2018-12-04` and it will returns me TRUE.

Is it possible with MySQL or I should write some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate start and end of the date range with help INTERVAL statement. For example:

```
SELECT
  t1.installend - INTERVAL 5 DAY, /*start date*/
  t1.installend + INTERVAL 5 DAY  /*end date*/
FROM <your table name>
```

Also, you can use BETWEEN statement to check exists of date in the date range. For example:

```
t1.insend BETWEEN t1.installend - INTERVAL 5 DAY AND t1.installend + INTERVAL 5 DAY
```

Comment: Hmm, I also tried with with BETWEEN, but ... Thank you!